Is there a Python's f-string equivalent in Matlab
I am wondering if there is a way to type and format strings in Matlab like how you have f-strings in Python:
Python input:
username = lemslems
text = f"Hello {username}!"

Output:
Hello lemslems!

I am asking this because I hate writing in the % format and it is just super convenient to write it like how I always do in Python

I once implemented this, you can get the function here: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/108829-interpolate_string — It’s not efficient, but very convenient.

Oh this is a good find. Why is this not efficient may I ask?

It's not efficient because the function has to run eval to evaluate the code inside the braces in the string. This could of course be very efficient if it were built into the language.

Matlab doesn't have a direct equivalent to Python's f-strings, but you can achieve similar functionality using string formatting or concatenation.
One way to do this is by using the sprintf function, which formats data into strings:
name = 'John';
age = 30;
formatted_string = sprintf('My name is %s and I am %d years old.', name, age);
disp(formatted_string);

Alternatively, you can use string concatenation:
name = 'John';
age = 30;
formatted_string = ['My name is ', name, ' and I am ', num2str(age), ' years old.'];
disp(formatted_string);

Both approaches will produce the following output:
My name is John and I am 30 years old.

These methods allow you to insert variables into strings similar to f-strings in Python.

Technically your second example is not string concatenation but character vector concatenation, and if you try to use that syntax with a string (e.g. name = "John"; - note the double quote marks) you won't get what you expected. You can concatenate actual strings with + (but that won't work if all your 'strings' are actually character vectors) or use append which should handle all eventualities.

Oh I did not realize there is a difference between single and double quotes in Matlab. Do you know why that is? But anyhoy that would save me from hours of frustration to come. Thank you!

@lems "Do you know why that is?" The single quotes (character vectors) are the classical way to do strings in MATLAB. Those have been in since the beginning. The double quotes were introduced in R2016b, to improve how you work with strings. You can now do "My name is " + name + " and I am " + age + " years old." (numbers concatenated to a string are converted to a string first). Also, ["foo","bar"] is an array of two strings. Read here for more information: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/characters-and-strings.html
